# Are these two SQL Statements equivalent? One works the other doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm learning SQL at w3schools. I was studying this chapter: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

I decided to use wildcards just to make it interesting.
The first SQL statement seems to work when I try it online  but not the second.
That's why  I would like to know if both SQL statements are equivalent or not.

1)

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS Total, Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE 'u%' OR Country LIKE 'g%' OR Country LIKE 'f%'
GROUP BY Country
HAVING Total > 5
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

2)

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS Total, Country
FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '[ugf]%' 
GROUP BY Country
HAVING Total > 5
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

It doesn't show error messsage it only shows "No result." when I try the second SQL statement here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_having

The first SQL statement does work.

Comment: And [tag:sql] is a language, it's not the brand of an RDBMS. Even though Microsoft SQL Server users often call their RDBMS "sql" for short, you should use the [tag:sql-server] tag to be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are equivalent only in SQL Server (and Sybase).  These extend the `LIKE` pattern to include character classes (the letters inside the square braces).

In other databases, `LIKE` patterns have only two wildcards `%` and `_`.  The square braces are just that, square braces.  It is unlikely that a country name would match them.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent if you are using T-SQL. `[]` syntax is Microsoft SQL Server/Sybase extension.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is a Sybase extension -- where SQL Server started, once upon a time.  Microsoft just kept it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, this only works in SQL Server and Sybase. The Oracle equivalent would require using the REGEXP_LIKE function to allow regular expression matching:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS Total, Country
FROM Customers
WHERE regex_like(Country, '^[ugf]','c')
GROUP BY Country
HAVING Total > 5
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```